# No view found for id bottomAppBar for fragment Fragment

Tags: java, android, xml

I recently transferred MapActivity into MapFragment. I've fixed all the issues except for this one

> No view found for id 0x7f080060 (com.example.policetracker:id/bottomAppBar) for fragment MapFragment{19507fe} (5f780415-46e3-4362-a236-d9b35c95d427 id=0x7f080060)

I'm also kind of new to Android Studio and XML.

Here is my MapFragment:

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback, ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;
private View mView;

Location currentLocation;
private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedClient;
private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 101;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
    return mView;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    fusedClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(requireActivity());
    getLocation();
}

private void getLocation(){
    if((ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
    ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            && (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)){

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_CODE);
        return;
    }

    Task<Location> task = fusedClient.getLastLocation();

    task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Location location) {
            if(location != null){
                SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
                assert supportMapFragment != null;
                supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(MapFragment.this);
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude());
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 17));
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            getLocation();
        }
    }
}
}
```

And here is my fragment_map

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MapFragment">

<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout="@android:layout/activity_list_item" />

<com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
    android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:fabCradleMargin="20dp"
    app:fabCradleVerticalOffset="10dp"
    app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="20dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

</com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/baseline_add_24"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomAppBar"
    android:contentDescription="TODO" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: I dont think you can have a Bottom App Bar in a fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out. I had to remove something in the original activity.

Comment: This answer isn't detailed, and is not likely to help future readers. Could you be more specific, by editing the answer?

Comment: Relevant xkcd: https://xkcd.com/979/

Comment: I forgot i had to delete all of the code in MpsActivity